# Limit multivarible

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How do I solve this limit?

$$\lim_{x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)} \frac{\sin(x^2+y^2+z^2)}{x^2+y^2+z^2+xyz} $$

This is equal to $$\frac{\sin(x^2+y^2+z^2)}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\times\frac1{1+\frac{xyz}{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$$

The first one is a standard limit with value one, but I'n not sure about the other term.

Comment: change to spherical coordinates. It'll become $\lim_{\rho\to 0}\frac{\sin(\rho^2)}{\rho^2+\rho^3 A(\theta)B(\phi)}$

Comment: What is the next step?

Comment: I made some changes, can you solve it now?

Answer (score 3):

Yes your idea is very good to put away the $\sin$ term, now we have that, for example by [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates)

$$\frac{xyz}{x^2+y^2+z^2} =r \cos \theta\sin \theta\cos^2 \phi\sin \phi $$

or as an alternative by AM-GM we can use that

$$x^2+y^2+z^2 \ge 3 \sqrt[3]{x^2y^2z^2} \implies \left|\frac{xyz}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right| \le \frac{|xyz|^\frac13}{3}$$

concluding in both cases by squeeze theorem.

Comment: Yeah, got it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

$0 \leq | \frac  {xyz} {x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}|\leq \frac  1 2 |z| \to 0$ since $|xy| \leq \frac 1  2{(x^{2}+y^{2})}$. Hence the given limit is $1$.